# How do I keep part of the character string used in regular expressions for pattern matching when replacing?

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I'm using `stringr` to help manipulate some html code stored in a character vector, the code looks like:

```
foo <- 'text-align:left;"> 4: Forging Foundations </td>\n'
```

In my full html code I have variations of what strings appear in place of `4: Forging Foundations` multiple times, and **I need to use the entirety of this section of code as the pattern to replace**. The final text output which I'm looking for is:

```
'text-align:left;background-color: #B0fff4 !important;"> 4: Forging Foundations </td>\n'
```

So I thought of using the `.` regexp with the `*` quantifier in place of `4: Forging Foundations`:

```
foo <- str_replace_all(
  foo,
  'text-align:left;">.*(?=</td>\n)',
  'text-align:left;background-color: #B0fff4 !important">.*(?=</td>\n)'
)
```

However this ends up replacing part of my original string with the regular expression syntax I used - I'm looking for some way to maintain that part of the character vector untouched.

Comment: Do you realize you can't use a regex pattern in the replacement string?

Comment: Yes after attempting this, I'm still newbie to regex..

Comment: Why use regex if you seem to replace hardcoded, fixed strings? Try `sub('text-align:left;">', 'text-align:left;background-color: #B0fff4 !important;">', foo, fixed=TRUE)`

Comment: There are other parts of my html code which feature `'text-align:left;"> ` but I don't want to replace those, only those which have a similar structure to `foo`.

Comment: Then, `gsub('text-align:left;">([^<]*</td>)', 'text-align:left;background-color: #B0fff4 !important;">\\1', foo)`? If you need to replace all occurrences, `gsub` seems to be a good-enough base R function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
gsub('text-align:left;">([^<]*</td>)', 'text-align:left;background-color: #B0fff4 !important;">\\1', foo)
# => [1] "text-align:left;background-color: #B0fff4 !important;\"> 4: Forging Foundations </td>\n"
```

The `([^<]*</td>)` part is a capturing group that matches any 0+ chars other than `<` and then `</td>` and then in the replacement pattern this part is restored using the `$1` replacement backreference.